# Закинуть Reporter TestNg в логи Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день. У меня есть готовые шаги в teamcity, в котором я запускаю Appium-сервер, запускаю свои авто-тесты, и после тестов у меня на выходе генерируется html-страничка, в которой я могу увидеть все, что я записал через Reporter.log(). Как эту страничку закинуть в teamcity в артефакты? Чтобы её можно было посмотреть и потыкать? Пробовал сделать как [тут](http://tctutorial.ru/teamcity/), но не получилось, так как я по-другому делаю отчет. 
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Как обычно разобрался сам, тему можно закрывать. Решение - добавить папку в zip, закинуть в teamcity путь до артефактов - путь до zip файла.

Comment: А ещё лучше делать в team-city вот так: **%AGENT_HOME%\путь до папки =>Report.zip** в графе Artifact paths, где AGENT_HOME - созданный вами параметр до рабочей папки. Тогда после окончания всех ваших шагов, в артефактах появится ваша папка, и там можно будет открыть html страничку.